# Rails freeze on a internal http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a internal http request, from one method to another method forwarding the info, but when i make the post the second method freeze all exactly in a query in the second method, i already  try to use another another database, new project, Any ideas on what is going on?

Routes

```
post 'rest/login'
post 'rest/verify_user/:email', to: 'auth#verify_user', as: 'verify', constraints: { email: /.*/ }
resources :users
```

Method 1

```
class RestController < ApplicationController 
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.json? } 
 def login 
    response = RestClient.post(verify_url(params[:email]), 
                              {'image' => params[:image]}.to_json,  
                              {content_type: :json, accept: :json})
 end
end
```

Method 2

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.json? }
 def verify_user
   email = params[:email]
   user  = User.find_by(email: email)    
   if user
     image = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
     diff =  distance_percent(user.image,image["image"])
     if diff <= 10 
        render status: 200
     else
        render status: 40
     end
   else
     render status: 404 
   end 
 end
end
```